# finding lag value for group of values

Tags: sql, hiveql, databricks

I have table like below

```
value 
 10
 10
 10
 20
 20
 30
 30
 30
 40     
 50
```

I need to create an additional column with lagged values like below

```
value   lag_value 
  10      NULL
  10      NULL
  10      NULL
  20      10
  20      10
  30      20
  30      20
  30      20
  40      30      
  50      40
```

Comment: What is the logic here?

Comment: What if (9, 10, ?)

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?

Comment: @Serg I have updated the question for your and everyone's clarification

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am looking for HiveQL syntax based solution.

Comment: Still it is not clear what if  value of a row id= 9 is 10? I.e. what is the ordering column for the sake of a query?

Comment: Look into gaps and islands problems.  Your question is actually fairly heavy.

Comment: @serg values in column `value` are ordered in ascending order so 10 cannot repeat again at rowid=9.

Comment: I see no rowid in the question.  But there's the `index` column. Is it relevant to the question? Drop it otherwise.

Comment: @Serg It was not relevant to question so i have dropped it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you for suggestion. I will read about it.

Comment: @stu has an answer then.

Comment: @Serg  It doesn't work with SQL used in Databricks notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, for your sample data you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select *,
  (select Max(value) from t t2 where t2.value < t.value) Lag_Value
from t
order by value;
```

[Example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=30122607f8c0a5fae437ca52484a6ed9)

Comment: It gives me error like `Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Correlated column is not allowed in a non-equality predicate`

Comment: I am trying  SQL query in databricks notebook

Comment: I've never used spark but it seems it doesn't fully support ansi sql, there are numerous other [similar questions with workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52256127/spark-sql-error-when-running-correlated-subquery)